# Is it a good idea to move all non-UI code to a different thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I've seen many examples where long-running code is executed asynchronously from an event handler. For example, here's an event handler for a button click in WPF:

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoWork());
}

private int DoWork()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { }
    return 42;
}
```

If `DoWork` was more complex, say wrote to a database, then multiple button clicks could cause multiple threads to try to write to the database at the same time.

What if, instead of having many of these `Task.Run` calls, one creates a new single `Thread` for all non-UI work. Tasks could be queued on this thread using something like `BlockingCollection`.

Because this thread is separate from the UI thread, the UI would still be responsive, and multiple button clicks would schedule the tasks (in order) to the same thread, avoiding concurrency issues.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: If you want to avoid multiple clicks, disable the button until the task is complete. I would avoid rolling my own task system.

Comment: If it's IO bound work like talking to a DB it shouldn't be using `Task.Run` at all, just async/await calls all the way down.  You only really need to spin up a thread if it's CPU bound work or if the IO doesn't expose async methods.

Comment: I'm with @RonBeyer: Why do you want to allow your user to make multiple clicks without waiting for previous click "result"? Is it a value for the application and its user? Most of the times, it's not. But it actually depends on your scenario

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What are you hoping to gain from all of the work you're proposing doing?

Comment: @Servy I'm hoping to gain some consistency in handling UI events. For example, there could be a class that is the "entry point" of all non-UI code to be done (and executed on its own thread). This would make it harder to accidentally run non-UI code on the UI thread by new developers. I'm also hoping to gain the piece of mind that the UI will be responsive regardless of the work being done---it could be long, it could be short---the point is that I don't even have to worry about it: it's all done on its own thread.

Comment: @redcurry And how is having a single thread handling all non-UI tasks through enqueued work accomplishing that any better than using the thread pool thread from the code in your question?

Comment: @Servy It would afford some safety (let's say a developer forgot to disable the button referenced above that writes to a file or database). It would also remove the need to know or remember when to call `Task.Run`. Because all non-UI tasks would be executed on a separate thread, the UI would be responsive without calling `Task.Run` in every event handler.

Comment: @redcurry How do you expect to know what handlers are and are not using the UI, and how are you expecting to run whatever ones you determine to not need the UI as needing to use this other method?  And synchronizing all non-UI work wouldn't stop someone from pressing the button multiple times before the work finishes, it just means it's building up a big queue of work to do, perhaps without the user even realizing it.  That could be worse.  If you don't want the user to be allowed to press the button while the operation is running, you need to disable the button.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is a `QueuedTaskScheduler` which could be found in parallel extensions.

That being said, I wouldn't simply queue all the operations. While you now have a responsive UI, it'll appear as if nothing is actually happening.

I wouldn't hesistate to do a Task.Factory.StartNew. A Task is not guaranteed to start a new thread. A Task and a Thread are two different things. The default task scheduler is smart enough to figure out if the required resources are available to start a new thread for the task. If you request a bunch of tasks to start at once, the queuing will happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Like many things, the answer is **it depends**. `async`/`await` all the way down is a good solution for I/O bound work as noted in the comments, and is the modern, preferred approach. `Task.Run()` is also ok.

The pattern you describe *can* certainly be used to do what you want and would be a decent solution for keeping the UI responsive. Before you queue the command to the thread, disable your button. When your command completes you could set the button state to enabled (by "enable/disable the button," I really mean changing a `bool` value on your view model). Your pattern is definitely suited to CPU bound work, but then so is `Task.Run()`

Your long running thread is basically a command queue, which can be advantageous if you need to serialize the work. So it can be a 'good' idea.

Answer (score 0):

For long running operation, it makes sense to use async in most of cases : [Keep the UI thread responsive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/keep-the-ui-thread-responsive).